# Does English have a word for "not sick"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, translation

In Danish, there is the word »rask« (I am sure there are similar words in other Germanic languages), which means either 'not sick' or 'quick'.  The latter sense is largely context dependent, and considered a bit old fashioned.

The advantage of the former meaning, is that one can ask »føler du dig rask?« (approx. 'do you feel not sick?').  I wonder if there is a word in English to convey the same meaning in a single word, so you can formulate the same kind of polar question.

The word 'healthy' (as in, 'do you feel healthy?') could also imply you lead a healthy lifestyle.  One can be not sick, while also being unhealthy.

Similarly, the word 'well' (as in, 'do you feel well?') - while closer - could also imply different meanings, as it has different connotations.  English is a second language to me, but I still have hard times grasping the exact meaning of 'well'.

And I feel, at times, that native English speakers have the same problem.  If someone asks, 'do you feel well?', and my financial situation is looking bleak, and it's worrying me, but technically I do not feel sick, I would probably answer 'no'.  But if someone asked me 'do you feel not sick?' in the same situation, I would answer 'yes'.

Am I misinterpreting the word 'well'?  Or does English lack a clear singular word meaning 'not sick', that has broad consensus in terms of meaning?  In Danish, since »rask« is an infrequently used word, its meaning is generally agreed upon.  Unlike 'well'.

Comment: In the medical sense, if a someone (esp. a child) is seeing a doctor for a check-up and feels healthy, those are called [well-child visits](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/001928.htm). Speaking as a native AmE speaker, I can not think of a word that fits what you are looking for.

Comment: In BrE if someone asks me "Do you feel well?" I know they are asking if I am not sick, not whether I am in touch with my feelings. Similarly "I am feeling unwell."

Comment: @WeatherVane Or if someone half-suspected you were ill, they might say "Do you feel alright?"

Comment: On the other hand, when I say "I feel good" that means I am in a good mood, happy, content etc. and probably (but not necessarily) physically healthy too — I might have a broken leg but be feeling positive about the future.

Comment: It should be noted, that the Danish word can be used without 'feeling', as in »er du rask?« (are you not sick?).  Doctors prefer to ask with the verb, 'to feel', as people can be sick without them knowing about it.  For instance, a questionnaire for being a blood donor will ask »føler du dig fuldstændig rask?« (do you feel thoroughly not sick?).  I am not sure you can ask 'do you feel thoroughly well?' without it sounding awkward.

Comment: I wouldn’t say _rask_ is an infrequently used word at all – it’s quite common. It’s just not **as** frequent as _well_, which is perhaps the most used of all English adverb.

Comment: I think if you told most British-English Speakers that you were not 'well' then said it was because of your finances, they would either assume you were so worried about money that it was making you ill or they would say 'I asked if you were 'well', not if you were 'well off'!'. Also, in British-English there is more of an assumption, though perhaps a declining one, that 'sick' means throwing up.

Comment: @Spagirl This has always been a very common false friend for Danes (and speakers of several other Germanic languages), since the local cognates of _sick_ (e.g., Danish _syg_) mean ‘ill’. The only sort-of exception I can think of is German, whose cognate, _siech_, is quite old-fashioned and literary and the normal word for ‘ill’ is instead _krank_.

Comment: @WeatherVane My children, (born 1977-82), when asked how they are, say they are "good". But this is a generational thing. As one born 1944, I would say "very well thankyou". ("How are you?" is essentially about your health.) When my kids say "good", I sometimes feel like saying "I was not asking about your moral status, I was concerned about your physical senses".

Comment: @WS2 I think it's a dialect issue: the use of "good" in North America and what "he did good" means.

Comment: It's common to find your own language clear and unambiguous and a language you are learning ambiguous and hard to understand. This is often because you intuitively understand the context in your own language, but not other languages you are less familiar with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"feeling well" is generally (as in almost always) used with health so yes, "Not sick" is synonymous with "well".

You can also use "in good health".

As pointed out above "feeling unwell" means "sick".

Although it should be noted that "sick" is ambiguous (nauseous, in bad health, unwell etc)

Comment: *Healthy* is also fine. The question itself is based on a faulty premise.

Comment: Would your answer be the same if the word was 'ill' rather than 'sick'?  I worry I may have made a mistranslation by using 'sick' rather than 'ill'.

Comment: @SVIP ''not ill' would be 'well', 'healthy' is more referring to general physical wellbeing but depending on context you could use 'feeling better', 'recovered' although they do presuppose you were ill.

"Are you ill?" "No, I feel well" "No, I feel OK", "No, I'm feeling good" for actions in the present.

 'Sick', as you correctly surmise, is ambiguous as, literally, it means nauseous.

Comment: I can't resist it... 'in the pink'.

Answer (score 1):

As an adverb, "well" does indeed mean "good" in a general sense (or rather the suppleted "goodly"). But as an adjective, it is used exclusively for health. "I feel well" can mean either that the speaker has good health, or that their ability to feel is good. The idiomatic use is always the former; a bad ability to feel (whether emotional or physical) is a sign of ill health anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A bit archaic, and therefore most often used jocularly, is the word *hale*. It also survives in the idiom *hale and hearty*.